# Save CSS rendered display to image file

Tags: css, image, save

Long and the short is (my only other post is about my invoice/quote database which I figured out). Anywho, basically, I pull information from the table ie: invoice display it and fondle it with CSS to get what is a fully working invoice for a customer; I do use the @media print for what the actual printout would look like. THAT is what I would like to be able to save as an image file. What the printer would see, I want to save as a redundant backup kind of thing (softcopy?). I have searched high and low and all I can find are screen capture programs and blah blah blah... I don't know if it can be done but my fingers are crossed. Thanks a bundle.

Comment: Would a PDF work for you?

Comment: @MarcAudet has it right - print it to a PDF.

Comment: There are server-side PDF generators that you can pass a URL to and they'll generate a downloadable file.

Comment: my issue is (don't know if a PDF print would work) we create invoices from (here we go) my desktop, partners desktop, our netbook, my phone, his phone and both our tablets :) Computers no problem, it's just we (Electricians) are on the road alot so can't get to our home computers to do stuff and have to "print" on the fly.

Comment: A PDF is easy to print and to email to your users/client.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with a PDF that you can save as a file, try:

http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk

This is uses one of the better rendering engines and it does a nice job of preserving your HTML/CSS formatting.

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention that it's not an actual webpage. It is the display that I create with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this on a web server?

Regardless, if you are printing to a pdf file, have a look at [PDFTK](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). It can be installed on any system: windows, osx, linux.

Comment: It is a webpage per-se, but the url would be with a variable so like www.somesite.ca?action=viewinvoice kind of thing